# Is there a way to fix this datetime error?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: time data '2022-01-20T15:30:57.2648531Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

here is my code:

```py
import datetime
 
date_string = '2022-01-20T15:30:57.2648531Z'
date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
unix_time = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_format)
print(unix_time)
```

I have tested removing the final number in the time data and it worked. It seems you can only have 6 numbers in the millisecond spot. Is there a way to bypass/fix this?

Comment: You should add back the 1 you removed from the answer's snippet so people can replicate the error.

Comment: According to the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

"When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from one to six digits and zero pads on the right."

Comment: the code i sent is the one that's giving me the error if that's what you mean

Comment: @NotClooudy I've edited the code in your question so that it produces the error you already got.

Comment: well is there a way to bypass this? or is there another way to convert to unix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems you can only have 6 numbers in the millisecond spot

It's actually microseconds, the `%f` specifier matches a 6-digit microsecond value. If you have a 7-digit number then the precision is more than one microsecond.

`datetime` objects do not support higher precision than microseconds, so you can just throw away the last digit. You can do this in multiple ways. Since according to your format specifier your string should always have the same length, you can simply trim it before converting.

```py
import datetime 

date_string = '2022-01-20T15:30:57.2648531Z'
date_string = date_string[:26] # trim anything past the 6th decimal digit

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
print(d.timestamp())
```

Since your date is in ISO format, you can also use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`, which should make your life easier:

```py
import datetime 

date_string = '2022-01-20T15:30:57.2648531Z'
date_string = date_string[:26] # trim anything past the 6th decimal digit

d = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)
print(d.timestamp())
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `datetime.datetime` class only supports microseconds ranging from `0` to `999999`. Observe:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 20, 15, 30, 57, 2648531)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 20, 15, 30, 57, 2648531)
ValueError: microsecond must be in 0..999999
>>>
```

But even if you go out of your way to separate the microseconds from the string to add to the `unix_time`, you will still run into the problem of losing the `1`:

```
import datetime
 
date_string = '2022-01-20T15:30:57.2648531Z'
index = date_string.rindex(".")
ms = float(date_string[index: -1])
date_format = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_string[:index], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
unix_time = datetime.datetime.timestamp(date_format) + ms
print(unix_time)
```

Output:

```
1642721457.264853
```

That is because python simply doesn't support such precision on floats:

```
>>> 1642721457.2648531
1642721457.264853
```

Comment: I get into this problem all the time when reading data from java rest apis using java.time that support nanoseconds. It is not much practical use, but I have to strip off the timezone part, then reduce the %f part to 6digits and then add the timezone part back on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `datetime` will only get you so far (6-digits). Use `pd.to_datetime` instead:

```
unix_time = pd.to_datetime(date_string)
print(unix_time.value)
```

Output:

```
1642692657264853100
```

Comment: Note that the final value is not what OP is looking for, you should divide that by 10**9 since OP wants the result in seconds.

Comment: It's just not possible, it will truncate.